# Visual Studio C++ removing last character from string

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, c++-cli, calculator

I need a little help with my calculator program. I have created the code for the main buttons like the numbers 0-9 and the arithmetic operators to make it perform simple calculations.

What I'm having problems with right now is making the CE button work, after clicking the CE button I need the last entered character to be removed from the display label.

I have tried to adapt this code somehow, but it doesn't work:

```
lblResult->substr(0, lblResult->size()-1);
```

I know I'm doing somehting wrong here, can you please help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You do realise `substr()` returns a new `string`, rather than modifying the object it's invoked on?  If you're doing that and expecting `lblResult` to have changed, just put a `lblResult =` in front (or to be more efficient, use `lblResult->erase(lblResult->size() - 1);`, or in C++11 use `lblResult->pop_back();`).

Comment: @crashmstr `lblResult` is the label that displays the calculation result

Comment: @user3124052 ...label? I think I figured that out, but what *class* is it? That is the part that could matter.

Comment: @TonyD I have tried `lblResult = lblResult->erase(lblResult->size() - 1); ` but I get an error **Error 2 error C2039: 'erase' : is not a member of 'System::Windows::Forms::Label' g:\---\---\---\newproject\newproject\Form1.h 1224**
 and the same for 'size'

Comment: @crashmstr It's in the form1 class generated by VS `public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form`

Comment: @user3124052: that explains a lot.  A `System::Windows::Forms::Label` is not a C++ Standard `std::string`, which is what everyone here assumed you meant (after all "removing last character from string"), and indeed you probably did mean that.  Sadly, you're operating in a .NET world on non-Standard data types.  You will need something roughly like `lblResult->Text = lblResult->Text.Remove(lblResult->Text.Length);`.  Check [here for the .NET String API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @user3124052 the correct tag for this "language" is c++-cli, also known as C++/CLI. It is .Net extensions to the language, and you should make sure you tag correctly in the future so we might be able to help you faster. I've added an answer that I think should work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...Now that we know that lblResult is a [System.Windows.Forms.Label](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), we can look at the documentation.

A `Label` has a [Text Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0cs4xb3d%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), which is a `String^` (i.e. a string reference).

For what you want to do, the [Remove Method of String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.remove%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is appropriate. But note in the documentation it says that it "Returns a new string in which a specified number of characters from the current string are deleted." This means that it does not modify the string, but returns a modified copy.

So to *change* the label's text, we need to assign to its `Text` property what we want: the current string with all of the characters except the last:

```
lblResult->Text = lblResult->Text->Remove(lblResult->Text->Length - 1);
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry for not being specific about the label type.

Answer (score 1):

```
lblResult->resize(lblResult->size() - 1);
```

Comment: Much better than substr.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use components Remove and Length methods.

Use the following code to access the components text:

`component->Text`

Than remove the last character of string by accessing Remove and component Length method

`= component->Text->Remove(component->Text->Length - 1)`

I hope you find this useful.

Answer (score -1):

Just asking the obvious -- the whole statement is

```
*lblResult = lblResult->substr(0, lblResult->size()-1);
```

right?

Comment: Why is this an answer and not a comment?

Comment: @cyber It's a rethorical question; I believe the answer to the rethorical question (that he thought substr() alters the string) is the answer to the OP's question.